# Groovy script to split date and time, and print it in format yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS

Tags: jenkins, groovy, timezone, datetime-format

From a Jenkins build it will return an output as `Change sets: (1901) ----$ Kivi "comment about the update done" 17-Dez-2021 02:10 PM`

I need to fetch only the date and time from this line `17-Sep-2020 02:15 PM` and return an output in timezone format as **yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS** using Groovy. Have anyone tried with this ? Can someone provide some inputs regarding the same. Thank you !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split and get date time using Linux and Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70392244/how-to-split-and-get-date-time-using-linux-and-batch)

Comment: No, I am asking it in Groovy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a `string` variable `initialDate` containing `17-Sep-2020 02:15 PM`, you can do:

```
initialDate = '17-Sep-2020 02:15 PM'
date = new Date(initialDate).format('yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS')
println date // display 20200917141500000
```

Comment: Thanks Brahim Ben Amira, it worked, used the code - testvar = myproperty.split()
println "splitvalue: "+ testvar[-3] + " "+testvar[-2] +  " "+testvar[-1] to split the date and time value :)